libgeos.py MemoryError on GeoDjango project
I'm developing a GeoDjango project on Rocky Linux 9 and deploying using Apache.  The application ran fine before when I used the standard Postgres database engine:
"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
but as soon as I swap to the PostGIS backend engine:
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
I get the following error:
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 7, in <module>
from .adapter import PostGISAdapter
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/adapter.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .collections import (  # NOQA
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/collections.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos import prototypes as capi
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.prototypes.coordseq import (  # NOQA
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/prototypes/coordseq.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.libgeos import CS_PTR, GEOM_PTR, GEOSFuncFactory
File "/home/centurion/centurion_web/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 88, in <module>
notice_h = NOTICEFUNC(notice_h)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
MemoryError

I hadn't even implemented any geospatial code in the application yet.  I have a development server on windows that the application runs normally on with that engine using the runserver command.
I've tried directly setting the GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH and GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH with no success.  I downgraded from django 5.0 to 4.2 with no success.

SOLVED IT!  It was an SELinux issue preventing access to certain files but showing up as a memory error.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
